# Envelope R Error

Tags: r, envelope

I'm trying to write a little script in R wich create a K Ripley's graph function in QGIS.

This is the code:

```
  ##Point pattern analysis=group
    ##Layer=vector
    ##Titulo=string
    ##Folder=folder
    ##showplots

    library("maptools")
    library("spatstat")


    K <- as.ppp(Layer)
    E <- envelope (K, fun=Kest, nsim=99)
    plot(E, main=Titulo)
    write.csv(K,Folder)
```

When I run the script i get the following message:

> Error en marks.ppp (Y, dfok=FALSE): Sorry, not implemented when the marks are a data frame.
>
> Calls:envelope->envelope.ppp->marks->marks.ppp
>
> Ademas: Mensaje de avisos perdidos
>
> 1: Some mark values are NA in the point pattern object. 
>   2: Some mark values are NA in the point pattern Y.

Anyone knows what am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `K` is a marked point pattern then `Kest` tries to do things with the pattern grouped by the mark, such as the cross-K-function. The mark here is usually a simple categorical vector which defines type-1 and type-2 points, for example in a case-control point pattern.

If the mark object in the `ppp` object is a data frame, it doesn't really know what to do with it. In this case the `SpatialPointsDataFrame` (converted by maptools, with a default bounding box window, which is probably a *bad thing*) keeps its data frame information, which is the QGIS attribute list, as the mark in the `ppp` object.

If you don't care about the point attributes and only the locations, then unmark the point pattern:

```
K <- unmark(as.ppp(Layer))
```